# Best approach for avoiding repetitive dynamic_cast?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I have a situation like

```
Shape *shape =dynamic_cast<Shape*>(obj);

if(dynamic_cast<Rectangle*>(obj))
{
   func();
   Rectangle* obj1 = dynamic_cast<Rectangle*>(obj);
   obj1->DoSomething1();
   obj1->DoSomething2();
}
else if(dynamic_cast<Circle*>(obj))
{
   func();
   Cirlce* obj2 = dynamic_cast<Cirlce*>(obj);
   obj1->DoSomething3();
   obj1->DoSomething4();
}
else if(dynamic_cast<Blah*>(obj))
{
   func();
   Blah* obj1 = dynamic_cast<Blah*>(obj);
   obj1->DoSomething5();
   obj1->DoSomething6();
}
...
...
```

What is the best approach for avoiding calling the `dynamic_cast` again inside a `if/else` statement and execute a method for that particular object type?

Comment: bad, don't do that.  google polymorphism

Comment: That's what virtual functions were invented for.

Comment: @pat: Question was incomplete

Comment: @n.m.: I know virtual functions. But this situation best approach?

Comment: I'm telling you what I use, you decide what's best for you.

Comment: Double dispatching is another good candidate to work around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should avoid such constructs and utilitize polymorphism the way it was intended to be used, eg:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething1();
        DoSomething2();
    }
};

class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething3();
        DoSomething4();
    }
};

class Blah : public Shape
{
public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething5();
        DoSomething6();
    }
};
```

```
Shape *shape = dynamic_cast<Shape*>(obj);
if (shape)
{
    func();
    shape->DoSomething(); 
}
```

If that is not an option for your code, you can do the following to remove the duplicate `dynamic_cast` calls, at least:

```
if (Rectangle *r = dynamic_cast<Rectangle*>(obj))
{
    func();
    r->DoSomething();
}
else if (Circle *c = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(obj))
{
    func();
    c->DoSomethingElse();
}
else if (Blah *b = dynamic_cast<Blah*>(obj))
{
    func();
    b->DoSomethingElseElse();
}
```

Comment: Is there any disadvantage of using this?